# Upgrading to bootstrap 4, menu doesn't hide

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to upgrade my entire project from bootstrap 3.3.0 to bootstrap 4.0.0, but an important element isn't shown as it should, a side menu.

This is the basic code of the menu:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var trigger = $('.hamburger'),
        overlay = $('.overlay'),
        isClosed = false;

    trigger.click(function() {
        hamburger_cross();
    });

    function hamburger_cross() {

        if (isClosed == true) {
            overlay.hide();
            trigger.removeClass('is-open');
            trigger.addClass('is-closed');
            isClosed = false;
        } else {
            overlay.show();
            trigger.removeClass('is-closed');
            trigger.addClass('is-open');
            isClosed = true;
        }
    }

    $('[data-toggle="offcanvas"]').click(function() {
        $('#wrapper').toggleClass('toggled');
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    position: relative;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

body,
html {
    height: 100%;
}

.nav .open>a,
.nav .open>a:hover,
.nav .open>a:focus {
    background-color: transparent;
}

/*-------------------------------*/
/*           Wrappers            */
/*-------------------------------*/

#wrapper {
    padding-left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled {
    padding-left: 220px;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
    z-index: 1000;
    left: 220px;
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -220px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background: #1a1a1a;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#sidebar-wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}

#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 220px;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 70px;
}

#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    margin-right: -220px;
}

/*-------------------------------*/
/*     Sidebar nav styles        */
/*-------------------------------*/

.sidebar-nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 220px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
    position: relative;
    line-height: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}

.sidebar-nav li:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    height: 100%;
    width: 3px;
    background-color: #1c1c1c;
    -webkit-transition: width .2s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: width .2s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: width .2s ease-in;
    transition: width .2s ease-in;
}

.sidebar-nav li:first-child a {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #1a1a1a;
}

.sidebar-nav li:nth-child(2):before {
    background-color: #ec1b5a;
}

.sidebar-nav li:nth-child(3):before {
    background-color: #79aefe;
}

.sidebar-nav li:nth-child(4):before {
    background-color: #314190;
}

.sidebar-nav li:nth-child(5):before {
    background-color: #279636;
}

.sidebar-nav li:nth-child(6):before {
    background-color: #7d5d81;
}

.sidebar-nav li:nth-child(7):before {
    background-color: #ead24c;
}

.sidebar-nav li:nth-child(8):before {
    background-color: #2d2366;
}

.sidebar-nav li:nth-child(9):before {
    background-color: #35acdf;
}

.sidebar-nav li:hover:before,
.sidebar-nav li.open:hover:before {
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: width .2s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: width .2s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: width .2s ease-in;
    transition: width .2s ease-in;
}

.sidebar-nav li a {
    display: block;
    color: #ddd;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px 15px 10px 30px;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:hover,
.sidebar-nav li a:active,
.sidebar-nav li a:focus,
.sidebar-nav li.open a:hover,
.sidebar-nav li.open a:active,
.sidebar-nav li.open a:focus {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.sidebar-nav>.sidebar-brand {
    height: 65px;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 44px;
}

.sidebar-nav .dropdown-menu {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    border: none;
    background-color: #222;
    box-shadow: none;
}
/*-------------------------------*/
/*       Hamburger-Cross         */
/*-------------------------------*/

.hamburger {
    position: fixed;
    top: 20px;
    z-index: 999;
    display: block;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
}

.hamburger:hover,
.hamburger:focus,
.hamburger:active {
    outline: none;
}

.hamburger.is-closed:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 32px;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}

.hamburger.is-closed:hover:before {
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100px, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}

.hamburger.is-closed .hamb-top,
.hamburger.is-closed .hamb-middle,
.hamburger.is-closed .hamb-bottom,
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-top,
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-middle,
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-bottom {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    height: 4px;
    width: 100%;
}

.hamburger.is-closed .hamb-top,
.hamburger.is-closed .hamb-middle,
.hamburger.is-closed .hamb-bottom {
    background-color: #1a1a1a;
}

.hamburger.is-closed .hamb-top {
    top: 5px;
    -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}

.hamburger.is-closed .hamb-middle {
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -2px;
}

.hamburger.is-closed .hamb-bottom {
    bottom: 5px;
    -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}

.hamburger.is-closed:hover .hamb-top {
    top: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}

.hamburger.is-closed:hover .hamb-bottom {
    bottom: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}

.hamburger.is-open .hamb-top,
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-middle,
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-bottom {
    background-color: #1a1a1a;
}

.hamburger.is-open .hamb-top,
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-bottom {
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -2px;
}

.hamburger.is-open .hamb-top {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .2s cubic-bezier(.73, 1, .28, .08);
}

.hamburger.is-open .hamb-middle {
    display: none;
}

.hamburger.is-open .hamb-bottom {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .2s cubic-bezier(.73, 1, .28, .08);
}

.hamburger.is-open:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 32px;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}

.hamburger.is-open:hover:before {
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100px, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}

/*-------------------------------*/
/*            Overlay            */
/*-------------------------------*/

.overlay {
    position: fixed;
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(250, 250, 250, .8);
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
    <title>loleo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <!--NO TOCAR-->
    <script src="sidebar.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="signup.css">
    <link href="sidebar.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="overlay"></div>
        <!-- SIDEBAR -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top navbar-expand-md" id="sidebar-wrapper" role="navigation">
            <ul class="nav sidebar-nav">
                <li class="sidebar-brand nav-item"> <a href="#" class="nav-link">

                       LOGO

                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item"> <a href="read.html" class="nav-link">READ</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item"> <a href="history.html" class="nav-link">HISTORY</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item"> <a href="notifications.html" class="nav-link">NOTIFICATIONS</a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown nav-item"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown">CONFIG<span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="profile.html">PROFILE</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="premium.html">PREMIUM</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="mainscreen.html">LOG OUT</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <!-- FIN DEL SIDEBAR -->
        <!-- INICIO DEL BODY -->
        <div id="page-content-wrapper">
            <button type="button" class="hamburger is-closed" data-toggle="offcanvas"> <span class="hamb-top"></span>
                <span class="hamb-middle"></span>
                <span class="hamb-bottom"></span>
            </button>
            <!--modificable desde aquí-->
            <!--hasta aquí-->
        </div>
        <!-- z -->
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

So, as you might have guessed, the menu should disappear totally when it's closed. I think a class is wrong, I have tried to change some of them, but don't know which one. Any idea?

Comment: remove the `margin` from your `body`

Comment: It is a good practice to put this `*{margin:0; padding:0; box-sizing: border-box; }` at the top of your css file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found the problem.

in

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top navbar-expand-md" id="sidebar-wrapper" role="navigation">
```

It's useless writting the "navbar" class of the css, it is superimposing, so "there are two sidebars". Just deleted this class from the label and finished.